# $af(a)+bf(b)+2ab$ is a perfect square for all $a,b \in \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, functional-equations

$\textbf{Question:} \\ $
Find all functions $f : N \to N$ for which the expression
$af(a) + bf(b) + 2ab$ is a perfect square for all $a,b \in \mathbb N$

$\textbf{My progress:}$

1.$ p \mid f(np) $ for all primes p and positive integer n.

2.$f(1)$ is a quadratic residue modulo infinitely many primes which (probably) implies $f(1)$ itself is a perfect square

3.all primes other than 2 can occur only once in the prime factor decomposition of $f(1)$

4.2 and 3 together gives $f(1)=2^k$. for even k.
Then using $2*f(1)+2$ being a perfect square we get $f(1)=1$

5.And I also noticed $f(a)=a$ works.

Here N means only the positive whole numbers.

Comment: Is in your case $0 \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: No.Here $N$ means only the positive whole numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not true that if $m$ is a quadratic residue modulo infinitely many primes, then $m$ must be a square. For example, $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo every prime that is congruent to $\pm 1$ modulo $8$, but $2$ is not a square.

Fortunately, it is true that if $m$ is a quadratic residue modulo *every* sufficiently large prime, then $m$ is a square.

For any natural number $a$, and any prime $p$, we have that
$$
  af(a) \equiv af(a) + pf(p) + 2ap \pmod p
$$
and so $af(a)$ is a square modulo every prime $p$. It follows that $af(a)$ is a square for every natural number $a$.

We will show that if $p$ is an odd prime then $f(p) = p$.

Suppose that $q \neq p$ is an odd prime such that $q \mid f(p)$.

Then $ qf(q) + pf(p) + 2pq $ is a square that is divisible by $q$, and hence by $q^2$. We note that $qf(q)$ is divisible by $q^2$, and so if $f(p)$ were divisible by $q^2$, then $2pq$ would be divisible by $q^2$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $f(p)$, and hence $pf(p)$, is divisible by $q$ only once, which is a contradiction since $pf(p)$ is a square.

Thus the only primes that divide $f(p)$ are $2$ (possibly), and $p$. Since $pf(p)$ is a square, we know that $p$ divides $f(p)$ an odd number of times.

Note that
$$
  2pf(p) + 2p^2
$$
is a square. If $f(p)$ were even, then the left hand side would be $2$ modulo $4$, which would be a contradiction. Thus, in fact, $2$ does not divide $f(p)$. We thus have that $f(p) = p^{2t + 1}$ for some natural number $t$.

We now note that
$$
  p^{2t + 2} + 2p + 1 = pf(p) + 1f(1) + 2p
$$
is a square.
But
$$
  (p^{t + 1})^2 < p^{2t + 2} + 2p + 1 \leq p^{2t + 2} + 2p^{t + 1} + 1 = (p^{t + 1} + 1)^2
$$
and so we must have that $t = 0$ and $f(p) = p$.

We now have that for every natural number $a$, and every odd prime $p$, that
$$
  af(a) + 2ap + p^2
$$
is a square, and so is equal to $(p + m_p)^2$ for some $m_p$ which depends on $p$.

We easily see that $0 < m_p \leq af(a)$ for all $p$. (We could probably find a better upper bound, but the point is that it is bounded by something that does not depend on $p$.)

Thus there are infinitely many primes $p$ with the same value of $m_p$. Let this value be $m$.

Then there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that
$$
  af(a) + 2ap + p^2 = p^2 + 2mp + m^2
$$
or
$$
  af(a) + 2ap = m^2 + 2mp
$$

Thus $af(a) - m^2$ is divisible by infinitely many primes $p$, and so $af(a) = m^2$. The equation then becomes $m^2 + 2ap = m^2 + 2mp$, and so $a = m$. Thus $af(a) = a^2$, and so $f(a) = a$ for all $a$.

Comment: There are other ways to finish off the problem once one knows that $f(p) = p$ for arbitrarily large $p$. e.g. The difference between $af(a) + 2ap + p^2$ and $(p + a)^2$ is $a^2 - af(a)$, which for large $p$ is smaller than the difference between $(p + a)^2$ and $(p + a \pm 1)^2$, and so we know that it must in fact be $0$.